# Set Cascade Delete for all entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to configure DeleteBehavior for all my entities. The Final result is that i can simply run:

```
DELETE FROM Companies Where Id = '1'
```

And all my 800 tables will be cleaned on cascade (All table references **CompanyId as FK**)...

**My Classes**

```
public interface ITest
{
    string PropX { get; set; }
    Company Company { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Reg {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Company {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Test : Reg, ITest
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string PropABC { get; set; }
    public string PropX { get; set; } = "My Info";
}

public class Test2 : Reg, ITest
{
    public string PropEFG { get; set; }
    public string PropX { get; set; } = "My Info2";
}

public class Test3 : Reg, ITest
{
    public string PropExample { get; set; }
    public string PropX { get; set; } = "My Info3";
}
```

If I do that, works perfect:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().HasOne(p=>p.Company).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Test2>().HasOne(p=>p.Company).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    //....... not for 800 classes

 }
```

But I Have 800 classes... So i'm trying do this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    var my800Entities = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().ToList();

    foreach (var entity in my800Entities)
    {
       modelBuilder.Entity(entity.Name).HasOne("Company").WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
       /* It seems to me that this code is creating an
       extra column and not defining the already existing property */
    }

}
```

The code above generate migration with one more column in each classe, example:

- *Other Properties...*
- Company (With FK restrict delete behavior)
- **Company1** (With FK **cascade** delete behavior)

What i need to do, for just 1 column (Company) with Cascade delete behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, filter the entity types that implement the interface:

```
var my800Entities = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .Where(t => typeof(ITest).IsAssignableFrom(t.ClrType))
    .ToList();
```

Then (and this is the main problem with your code), pass both related type and navigation property name to the `HasOne` method (currently you are passing just the related type name, which is equivalent of the parameterless generic `HasOne` and indicates relationship *without* navigation property, hence EF Core associates *another* relationship with that property):

```
foreach (var entity in my800Entities)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity(entity.Name)
       .HasOne(typeof(Company), "Company") // <--
       .WithMany()
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, you are the best! Thank you so much!